# eBay API in Sandbox returns response as a continuous string

Tags: sandbox, ebay-api, responseformat

Just started using the eBay API.

I created some products and purchased it with another Sandbox account.
In the Sellers account, I can see 2 products under the 'Sold' section.

I am using the `GetOrders` API call to fetch the orders/sales.
And in the response I am getting a continuous string.

```
2013-04-20T07:28:55.919ZSuccess819E819_CORE_API_15993720_R111false260765010Completed0.038.00.0NoPaymentFailure2013-04-09T07:15:25.000ZPayPalCompletefalse0.0false0.0StandardShippingFromOutsideUS4.01false510103falseBuyer2013-04-09T07:15:25.000ZPayPalTest UseraddresscityWAUSUnited States1 800 111 1111981026806769eBayStandardShippingFromOutsideUS4.034.038.0xxx.yyy@gmail.com1012013-04-06T11:32:41.000Z110115066261US1000New1None023.0112.51USeBay2.00.0110115066261-0xxx.yyy@gmail.com1022013-04-09T07:13:20.000Z110115066411US1000Brand New1None2705398200111.078.41USeBay2.00.0110115066411-27053982001testuser_xxxyyy252013-04-09T07:15:25.000ZfalsenY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6wFk4GhCpKBpwidj6x9nY+seQ==None10011
```

I don't see any labels associated with the values, like `date = 2013-04-09T07:15:25.000Z`

And why is it not formatted?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Also is there any other method by which I can retrieve the sale's for a particular period.

Comment: can you post some code on how you handle response?

Comment: Please refer to this link for the code: https://snipt.net/anishnair/ebay-api-call-to-fetch-the-salesorders/?key=687fd0e1f48782e592d88f451cfd0fc7

Answer (score 0):

as i thought your problem is when you `echo` the answer, your browser will automatically set header as html and that cause your view. so just add xml header at the top of the file (rember to not echo anything else but one xml otherwise you will get header error).

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

About your question about filter by time your response i would definitly go for `NumberOfDays` as i saw you used. Otherwise you can either add `ModTimeFrom` and `ModTimeTo` for last `x` time modified orders or `CreateTimeFrom` and `CreateTimeTo` to check new orders entered.

Comment: Still the same result Fabio. Thanks for your help though. What you can do is try it with your credentials if you have an Ebay Sandbox.